# VirtualizingPanel acts weird with many many Children

Tags: c#, wpf, virtualization

Hiho,
im facing serious issues implementing a Horizontal VirtualizingPanel the right way. Virtualization works so far and items are positiones at the right positions but when i scroll though the items, some items start overlapping(for me at Item 671090) and the following Items start creating gaps between each other. This effect increases depending on the horizontal offset.
I already tried to locate the Problem watching the itemposition in Debug but its all as it intends to be. Different Implementations found in the internet have the same problem.
I tried the VirtualizingTilePanel Implementation provided by Dan Crevier and the StaggeredPanel described in "SAMS WPF Control Development unleashed".
Both seem to have the same Problem when i add a lot of items.

Steps to reproduce: 
1. Download Example from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/16/implementing-a-virtualizingpanel-part-4-the-goods.aspx

or sample code from

http://www.informit.com/store/wpf-control-development-unleashed-building-advanced-9780672330339

1. Add for example 1000000 items for Virtualization.
2. Scroll through Data
3. Problem starts for me at item 671090(maybe depending on architecture?)

edit: Itemswidth is set to 100.0,
Problem occurs at the same index for my colleagues

Any help would be really nice.

Thank you and greetings

Comment: Hmmm... 671090 is roughly (2**31 - 1) / 3200.  Here's some speculation: perhaps WPF uses internal units of 1/32 of a pixel (so your items are 3200 of these units wide), and with 671090 items, that overflows the range of a signed `int`.

Comment: Mh the idea is good. I Already had the same. but WPF uses 1/96.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Now that you mention it, 1/96 seems familiar to me.  Nonetheless, I do have to ask: why you need so many items in a single control?

Comment: im programing a software to visualize genome data. I need to visualize nearly infinite numbers of items(250 Million is the minimum requiremend for the human genome). I should mention that i use datavirtualization too.

Comment: To better understand the problem heres a picture. There the problem starts.http://imageshack.us/f/826/samplejh.jpg/